# Scroll up to highlight div on validation failure

Tags: jquery, css, jsp, html, scroll

I have a form (jsp page) and contains a div where the error message is shown if any.
When a user submits the form, the validations are done server side and based on any violation an error message field is set which is displayed in the JSP using struts property tag inside a div.

Now the problem is, since my form has many fields, hence the submit button is placed way below and error div is above the form hence in case of error, the message do gets displayed but user need to scroll up to look for the error message.
What i need is, as the error occurs, the page should get scrolled up automatically and error should get highlighted.

I am ok with any jquery or css solution if possible. Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use ScrollTop functions, to scroll to a div.

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click',function(){

 //if is any error found. then do this
    $(window).scrollTop($('#yourErrorDiv').offset().top);
});
```